# Format for saving full web page background video

Tags: html, video, responsive

I am putting together a web site with a full page background video.

I am editing and saving a long video into a short video(s). The formats I am saving them to is mp4 and webm.

My problem is that they are not displaying as full web page background videos instead they show as smaller videos centered in the background which is not what I want. I am assuming that its because I am not saving with the right codec/specs.

The choices in OpenShot video editor are many.
Can someone assist me with what I should choose for the following:

** MP4 **

### video settings

Video format: mp4

Video codec:
Bit rate / quality:

### video profile

height:
width:
fps:
aspect ratio:
frame rate:
pixel ratio:
progressive:

** WEBM **

### video settings

Video format: webm
Video codec:
Bit rate / quality:

### video profile

height:
width:
fps:
aspect ratio:
frame rate:
pixel ratio:
progressive:

Thanks so much:-)

Comment: you'll need to ensure the `<video>` container is scaled to 100% to fit the frame, otherwise video is going to display at whatever size you created

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.